# click event triggers when click is performed on next tag- Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

The below clicked() function is triggering when a click is performed on the below label. It does not trigger when click is performed on glyphicon icon.

```html
<div>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart" [class.highlight]="isActive" (click)="clicked()"></span>
</div>
<div><label >{{count}}</label></div>
```

This is the css File

```css
.glyphicon{
    color:#ccc;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.highlight{
    color:deeppink;

}
```

This is the ts file

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input,Output,EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'likecounter',
  templateUrl: './likecounter.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./likecounter.component.css']
})
export class LikecounterComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() count = 0
  @Input() isActive = false
  @Output() click = new EventEmitter()


  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  clicked(){
    this.click.emit()
  }

}
```

Comment: your code should be fine. can you create stackblitz for that?

Comment: Agree with @StacksQueue. Code seems to be ok. May be some css issue. If possible create stackblitz.

Comment: I have updated the post with css and ts code. Thanks for looking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing output event name form **click** to someothername worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert some content in span, so it may be visible in DOM.

```
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart" [class.highlight]="isActive" 
        (click)="clicked()">Click Me</span>
```

This will solve your issue.

Comment: This didn't work. and I also don't want to use any text. I need to perform an action when glyphicon-heart is clicked.